# Why i get error"ResultSet object is not callable" when i try parse HTML text file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to receive information about each lot posted on the site. And later, through pandas, pack it into a table. I ran into a problem in line 20. Began to redo the search from one subject to all. Throws this error.

Thanks)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRKJx.png)

```
import requests                 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/"
headers = {'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)    

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")



items = soup.findAll('a', class_= 'market_listing_row_link')

data = []


for item in items:
    quality = items.find("div", class_= "market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult").find('div', class_= "market_listing_price_listings_block").find('span', class_="market_table_value").text
    #print("Кол-во лотов: "+ quality)
    normprice = soup.find('div', class_= 'market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult').find('div', class_= "market_listing_price_listings_block").find('span', class_="normal_price").text
    #print("Norm price "+ normprice)
    games = soup.find('div', class_= 'market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult').find('div', class_= "market_listing_item_name_block").find('span', class_="market_listing_game_name").text
    #print("Game :"+ games)
    data.append([quality, normprice, games])
```

`

I tried to change findAll to find_all

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo inside your for loop:

```py
...

for item in items:
    # Your code had `items.find`
    quality = item.find("div", class_= "market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult").find('div', class_= "market_listing_price_listings_block").find('span', class_="market_table_value").text

...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are doing:

```py
for item in items:
    quality = items.find("div", class_= "market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult").find('div', class_= "market_listing_price_listings_block").find('span', class_="market_table_value").text
```

you are calling `items.find()` but `items` is really your `list`:

```
items = soup.findAll('a', class_= 'market_listing_row_link')
```

So instead of:

```py
for item in items:
    quality = items.find("div", class_= "market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult").find('div', class_= "market_listing_price_listings_block").find('span', class_="market_table_value").text
```

use (notice there's no "s" in "item":

```py
for item in items):
    quality = item.find("div", class_= "market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult").find('div', class_= "market_listing_price_listings_block").find('span', class_="market_table_value").text
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, to load the lots using their Ajax API:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/'

params = {
    "query": "",
    "start": "10",
    "count": "10",
    "search_descriptions": "0",
    "sort_column": "popular",
    "sort_dir": "desc",
}


all_data = []

for page in range(3):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    params['start'] = page * 10
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data['results_html'], 'html.parser')

    for row in soup.select('.market_listing_row_link'):
        name = row.select_one('.market_listing_item_name').text
        game = row.select_one('.market_listing_game_name').text
        qty = row.select_one('.market_listing_num_listings_qty').text
        price = row.select_one('.normal_price[data-currency]').text
        url = row['href']
        all_data.append((name, game, qty, price, url))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['Name', 'Game', 'Qty', 'Price', 'URL'])
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Name | Game | Qty | Price | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dreams & Nightmares Case | Counter-Strike: Global Offensive | 165,016 | $0.53 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case |
| Recoil Case | Counter-Strike: Global Offensive | 237,270 | $0.58 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Recoil%20Case |
| Clutch Case | Counter-Strike: Global Offensive | 356,950 | $0.29 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Clutch%20Case |
| Mann Co. Supply Crate Key | Team Fortress 2 | 13,357 | $2.21 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Mann%20Co.%20Supply%20Crate%20Key |
| Operation Breakout Weapon Case | Counter-Strike: Global Offensive | 35,759 | $3.87 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Operation%20Breakout%20Weapon%20Case |